# Global variable in iOS TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, properties, uitabbarcontroller

Can I create some `@property` in the TabBarViewController class, which i will call in subViewControllers and change it in subViewCintrollers' method `viewWillApper`?

Comment: You're not supposed to subclass UITabBarController (stated in the docs) and your contained view controllers needing knowledge of, and access to, their container is a bad code smell. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i wanna to know which of the subView was before the presnet View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just creating `@property` in target `VeiwController` and set this @property firstly in viewDidLoad. So i know that firstly this ViewController will appear from TabBar. After that i can change it in some other ViewController's methods, which call some subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the tab bar controller delegate method `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`. This will be called before your tab bar changes selection. At this point, the tab bar controller's `selectedViewController` will be the current one - so you have a pointer to the current and next selection.